# global変数を使わずにコードを機能させたい

Tags: python

`short.sequ.txt`から`>YP`で始まる行をそのままprintし、その次の行から空白を認識するまでの文字数をカウントする。
この作業を繰り返し行い、最大の文字数と最大の文字数の時の`>YP`の行を最終的にprintしたいと思ってます。
最大値が見つかるたびにmax_lenとmax_proteinを更新したいです。（最小値も同じく）

global変数を用いて作成したのですが、できればglobal変数を使わずにこのようなコードを書きたいと思ってます。
その場合、global変数をどういったものに変えたらいいのかわからないので教えていただきたいです。
宜しくお願い致します。

```python
with open("short.sequ.txt") as f:

    max_len = 0
    max_protein = ""

    min_len = 10000000000000
    min_protein = ""

    def change(protein, seq):
        global max_len,max_protein,min_len,min_protein
        seq_len = len(seq)
        if seq_len == 0:
            return

        else:
            print([seq_len])

        if seq_len > max_len:
            max_len,max_protein,min_len,min_protein = seq_len,protein,seq_len,protein

        if seq_len < min_len:
            min_len,min_protein = seq_len,protein


    a_line = ""
    a_seq = ""

    for line in f:
        strip_line = line.rstrip()
        if strip_line.startswith(">"):
            a_line = strip_line
            change(a_line, a_seq)
            a_seq = ""
            print(strip_line+'\n')
        else:
            #A = [len(a_seq+strip_line)]
            a_seq += strip_line
msg1 = "最大アミノ酸エントリ："
msg2 = "長さ："
msg3 = "最小アミノ酸エントリ："
print(msg1,max_protein,msg2,max_len)
print(msg3,min_protein,msg2,min_len)
```

**short.sequ.txt**

```text
>YP_009518834.1 putative uncharacterized protein YjiT [Escherichia coli str. K-12 substr. MG1655]
MGQSEYISWVKCTSWLSNFVNLRGLRQPDGRPLYEYHATNDEYTQLTQLLRAVGQSQSNICNRDFAACFV
LFCSEWYRRDYERQCGWTWDPIYKKIGISFTATELGTIVPKGMEDYWLRPIRFYESERRNFLGTLFSEGG
LPFRLLKESDSRFLAVFSRILGQYEQAKQSGFSALSLARAVIEKSALPTVFSEDTSVELISHMADNLNSL
VLTHNLINHKEPVQQLEKVHPTWRSEFPIPLDDETGTHFLNGLLCAASVEAKPRLQKNKSTRCQFYWSEK
HPDELRVIVSLPDEVSFPVTSEPSTTRFELAICEDGEEVSGLGPAYASLENRQATVRLRKSEVRFGRQNP
SAGLSLVARAGGMIVGSIKLDDSEIAIGEVPLTFIVDADQWLLQGQASCSVRSSDVLIVLPRDNSNVAGF
DGQSRAVNVLGLKALPVKGCQDVTVTANETYRIRTGREQISIGRFALNGKRASWVCHPDETFIGVPKVIS
TLPDIQSIDVTRYTC

>YP_009518833.1 uncharacterized protein YtiA [Escherichia coli str. K-12 substr. MG1655]
MKEFLFLFHSTVGVIQTRKALQAAGMTFRVSDIPRDLRGGCGLCIWLTCPPGEEIQWVIPGLTESIYCQQ
DGVWRCIAHYGVSPR

>YP_009518832.1 iraD leader peptide [Escherichia coli str. K-12 substr. MG1655]
MENEHQYSGARCSGQAAYVAKRQECAK

>YP_009518831.1 protein YtiD [Escherichia coli str. K-12 substr. MG1655]
MADYAEINNFPPELSSSGDKYFHLRNYSEYSEYTSGFFLSLMIFIKS

>YP_009518830.1 protein YtiC [Escherichia coli str. K-12 substr. MG1655]
MPVNGIFDVFDMLSIYIIYKLIVSNNTWLIMRK

>YP_009518829.1 putative YjfA [Escherichia coli str. K-12 substr. MG1655]
MHMVTYPCLTSRRFQLALIHRRVVDKRTSMHSRTASESTGARIHRPWCARHQVRPAWRCQYDKLHRVPFR
SPELRLDSGPGYTTGSYRY
```

Comment: このコードだと`short.sequ.txt`の最後の`>YP_009518829.1 putative YjfA [Escherichia coli str. K-12 substr. MG1655]`が最大・最小の判定に含まれてないかと。それも含めて修正しても良いですかね？

Comment: 確かに、そうでした。ぜひ宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 繰り返しでごめんなさい。これって、最大アミノ酸エントリは`>YP_009518834.1 putative uncharacterized protein YjiT [Escherichia coli str. K-12 substr. MG1655]`で、最小アミノ酸エントリは`>YP_009518832.1 iraD leader peptide [Escherichia coli str. K-12 substr. MG1655]`という対応関係でよいのですかね？　このコードだと、最大・最小と判定されたのアミノ酸エントリの名前が下のブロックのアミノ酸エントリに対応しちゃってますね。

Comment: 結果これです。最大アミノ酸エントリ： >YP_009518833.1 uncharacterized protein YtiA [Escherichia coli str. K-12 substr. MG1655] 長さ： 505
最小アミノ酸エントリ： >YP_009518825.1 putative PTS enzyme II component GlvC [Escherichia coli str. K-12 substr. MG1655] 長さ： 26
>>>

Comment: 最大値の時（これでゆう５０５）に上の行を表示、最小値の時に上の行を表示といった結果を得たいです

Comment: わかりづらくて申し訳ありあリマセン。

Answer (score 2):

以下では、`short.sequ.txt` の内容を空行(`\n\n`)で分割して、個々の protein sequence の長さでソートしています。

```
import re

msg1 = "最大アミノ酸エントリ："
msg2 = "長さ："
msg3 = "最小アミノ酸エントリ："

with open("short.sequ.txt") as f:
  assoc = {}
  for p in f.read().split("\n\n"):
    if not re.match('^>YP_', p): continue
    arr = p.split("\n")
    assoc[arr[0]] = sum(map(len, arr[1:]))
  sa = sorted(assoc.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])

  print('{} {}\n{} {}'.format(msg1, sa[-1][0], msg2, sa[-1][1]))
  print('{} {}\n{} {}'.format(msg3, sa[0][0], msg2, sa[0][1]))

=>
最大アミノ酸エントリ： >YP_009518834.1 putative uncharacterized protein YjiT [Escherichia coli str. K-12 substr. MG1655]
長さ： 505
最小アミノ酸エントリ： >YP_009518832.1 iraD leader peptide [Escherichia coli str. K-12 substr. MG1655]
長さ： 27
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。非常に参考になりました。また機会がありましたら宜しくお願いします。